# Android check rom version

Tags: android, rom

I want to unlock (s-off) my HTC Desire HD. After reading some tutorials I learned that I should downgrade temporarily my rom to 1.32. But there is a catch, you must have rom 1.72 or higher.

On my phone I have Android 2.3.2  with CyanogenMod7 I bought the phone second-hand and that's why I have no idea what version was flashed.

Compilation number is: GRH78C

I'm not quite sure what this 'rom version' means and how to check what varsion I have. I suppose it's not the same as Android version because I can't see anything like 1.32 or 1.72 on Wikipedia's list of versions.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have 2.3.x then it is gingerbread. Higher version than 1.72 (froyo). 
However, if you have a custom rom your phone might be already rooted.